# Asking for a proof for the number of free variables in a consistent linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any system of linear equations, we can represent it by an augmented matrix and turn the matrix into (reduced) row echelon form.

> Let $p$ denote the number of pivots in the (reduced) row echelon form and $n$ denote the number of unknowns in the system. If the system is consistent, then there are $n-p$ unknowns whose value can be assigned arbitrarily, and in particular, we can always be sure that if column $i$ of the (reduced) row echelon matrix does not contain a pivot, then we can choose to assign arbitrary value to the unknown $x_i$.

It's quite obvious to "see" that the above statement is true whenever we have an example of (reduced) row echelon matrix representing a consistent linear system. But may I ask how to *prove the above statement in a rigorous manner*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated the answer if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Hi JAS! Is there any way I can expand my answer to help you better?

Comment: @AlexD Hi Alex, thank you for your reply, sorry I was on something else and just saw your answer. I'll read it now and come back to you if I have any question related. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$, and that you were trying to find a vector $x$ such that $Ax=b,$ for some vector $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Also suppose you were able to find a solution, call it $x_{p}$, by putting the augmented matrix $A|b$ in reduced row echelon form. This is only one solution. The complete solution $\hat x$ is given by $$\hat{x}=x_{p}+x_{n},\tag{$\star$}$$ where $x_{n}$ is **ANY** vector in the null space of $A$.

Remember that the null space is the set of all vectors $x$ such that $Ax=0$. Then $\hat{x}$ is indeed the complete solution since we have
$$
     \begin{alignat*}{2}
          A\hat{x}&=A(x_{p}+x_{n})\\
                  &=Ax_{p}+Ax_{n}\\
                  &=(b)+(0)\\
                  &=b.
     \end{alignat*}
$$

---

**To answer your question:**
Having $p$ column pivots means you have $p$ linearly independent column vectors, so the dimension of the column space of the matrix is $p$.

The dimension of the null space must then be $(n-p)$, so a list of $(n-p)$ independent vectors span the null space.

Suppose $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-p}$ is such a list of $(n-p)$ independent vectors spanning the null space of A. Since the null space is a vector space, it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. This means that any linear combination of $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-p}$ will be in the null space of A. That is to say, the vector $$x_{n}=a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+...+a_{n-p}x_{n-p}$$ is in the null space, for arbitrary coefficients $a_{i}$.

Then the complete solution from $(\star)$ becomes
$$
     \begin{alignat*}{2}
          \hat{x}&=x_{p}+x_{n}\\
                 &=x_{p}+(a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+...+a_{n-p}x_{n-p}),
     \end{alignat*} 
$$
where we can pick arbitrary values for $a_{1},...,a_{n-p}$. These are the $(n-p)$ arbitrary unknowns you mention in your question.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the answer is good by far I can see. The only thing is that I guess I need to recap some linear algebra to see why every solution is included in the form $\hat{x}=x_{p}+x_{n}$ and why the dimension of null space is related to the dimension of the column space by $n-p$. If you could include some hints for them that would be great :) Also, may I ask if similar argument could be used for generalisation to arbitrary field (other than $\mathbb{R}$)?